# Any way to make Apache's internal redirect work?

Tags: plugin-development, url-rewriting, redirect, urls, rewrite-rules

What I really want to do is to make URLs like

`http://localhost/bmicalc/bmi24.57`

to redirect to

`http://localhost/bmicalc/index.php?pagename=bmi&result=24.57`

without changing the URL in the browser. It's relatively easy to do with Apache's `.htaccess` rules, but it seems that WordPress ignores `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URI']` entirely, so an internal redirect can't be done without some hacking.

What I've found so far is this (very ugly) solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467221/wordpress-permalinks-and-redirection/32468918#32468918

Is there a better and more obvious way to go about it?

Comment: If you're already using pretty permalinks, then [add an internal rewrite rule](https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule).

Comment: Can you elaborate? When I tried doing it with `add_rewrite_rule()`, it would always change the URL in the browser. Can you, please, show me an example with this function that doesn't change the displayed URL?